# Windows 8 64-bit through VirtualBox has network problems (32-bit works fine) - what to do?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, windows-8-preview

Base system is Vista 64-bit running VirtualBox 4.1.2

The network in the Windows 8 32-bit version works correctly in this setup but Windows 8 64-bit does not.  By "not working" I mean that Windows cannot see the network and its troubleshooter states "Windows did not detect a properly installed network adapter"

Here is what I did in VirtualBox for the 32-bit VM:
(In Settings | Network | Adapter 1)

- Attached to: Bridged Adapter
- Name: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
- Adapter Type: **Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop (82540OEM)**
- Promiscuous Mode: Deny

This works, and I noticed that the "adapter type" dropdown is enabled so I could select another brand if so inclined.

For the 64-bit VM:

- Attached to: Bridged Adapter
- Name: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
- Adapter Type: **PCnet-FAST III (Am79C973)**
- Promiscuous Mode: Deny

"Adapter Type" is fixed to this wrong value, and I suspect that is why Windows 8-64 doesn't think it has any network hardware installed.

Any ideas?

Comment: It is pre-beta software and bound to be full of all sorts of bugs that cannot be remedied. Also, they may not have included a 64bit driver for that particular network adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure the VM is shutdown before you can change the Network Adapter Type.  Then it shouldn't be fixed anymore.  That worked for me at least.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I had screwed up the current state of VirtualBox and its VMs - when you rename a VM to something with a "?" in it all hell breaks loose as well.

Rebooting and restarting worked (essentially what Dr. Zebra says above so I'll mark that as the answer).

Also [this VirtualBox forum topic](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=44577) is useful for similar issues